# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.connect()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, api, android-studio, admob

Hi everyone I just have a question. When I add the Admob code to my main activity shall add the code to all of my layout codes or only the main one?

[image]